# Projection for Germany that preserves distance?

Tags: coordinate-system, point, distance, germany

I have a `point A` (EPSG 4326) in Berlin, Germany:

```
{
   "type": "Point",
   "coordinates": [
     13.394994735717773,
     52.514849775310154
   ]
}
```

I want to create `point B` that is 500m to the east of `point A` and `point C` that is 500m to the North.

For this, I have to project `point A` to a projection that preserves distance.

Can you recommend a projection that works for this operation in entire Germany?

I am working with GeoPandas and Shapely for this project.

Comment: What are the requierements for the accuracy? For 500m it might be negligible to use the UTM Zone 33 as the deviations around 13.4° are around 25cm per kilometer for this projection.

Comment: 25cm per kilometer is totally fine. Minimum requirement would roughly be 1m per km.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need an equidistant projection, but geodetic distances calculated on a spheroid ([Vincenty's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty's_formulae)) or a sphere ([Great-cicle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance)).
For instance, `geopy` is able to calculate them.

> Here’s an example usage of Vincenty distance:
>
> ```
> >>> from geopy.distance import vincenty
> >>> newport_ri = (41.49008, -71.312796)
> >>> cleveland_oh = (41.499498, -81.695391)
> >>> print(vincenty(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles)
> 538.3904451566326
> ```
>
> Using great-circle distance:
>
> ```
> >>> from geopy.distance import great_circle
> >>> newport_ri = (41.49008, -71.312796)
> >>> cleveland_oh = (41.499498, -81.695391)
> >>> print(great_circle(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles)
> 537.1485284062816
> ```

Source: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy#measuring-distance

---

> how to find point B with the above-described method?

You need to solve the [direct problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty's_formulae#Direct_Problem), i.e. given an initial point, its azimuth and a geodesic distance calculate the final point. A Python implementation of the direct problem is available in the [PyGeodesy package](https://pythonhosted.org/PyGeodesy/docs/pygeodesy.ellipsoidalVincenty.LatLon-class.html#destination).

Example:

```
>>> from pygeodesy.ellipsoidalVincenty import LatLon 
>>> p = LatLon(-37.95103, 144.42487)
>>> d = p.destination(54972.271, 306.86816)
>>> print d.lon, d.lat
143.926497668 -37.6528177174
```

Comment: Thanks @afalciano! This opens up a new perspective. Since I don't want to measure distance, I am wondering if you have a recommendation on how to find point B with the above-described method?

Comment: I suggest using the pygeodesy package to solve the direct problem. See the updated answer above.

Answer (score 3):

> For this, I have to project point A to a projection that preserves
>   distance (Equidistant).

You may have misunderstood "Equidistant" in Equidistant projections. It's a common misunderstanding that "Equidistant" projections preserves distances everywhere, which is impossible due to one of Gauss's theorems.

Some projections are called "Equidistant" because they preserve distance along a set of specific lines, such as meridians or parallels, which are called **standard lines**.

If in your case, points A and B are always to the East/West of each other, then in [Sinusoidal projection, all parallel lines are standard](http://www.progonos.com/furuti/MapProj/Dither/CartProp/DistPres/distPres.html).

Otherwise, you can use the spheroidal distance e.g. by computing distance directly with your points in lat/long (EPSG 4326) using PostGIS's [geography type](https://postgis.net/docs/geography.html).

Comment: Thank you @tinlyx for the detailed answer. I edited my question a bit by specifying the technology I am using (PostGIS is unfortunately not an option) and added the requirement that I want to create also a point to the north of point A (which I think eliminates the Sinusoidal projection as an option).

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need accuracy down to the millimeter, you can just use one of the common transverse Mercator coordinate systems for this area, UTM zone 33 (EPSG 32633) or [Gauß-Krüger](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gau%C3%9F-Kr%C3%BCger-Koordinatensystem) zone 4 (EPSG 31468):

```
gk4_data = latlon_data.to_crs(epsg=31468)
```

Berlin is near a zone border in both systems, which results in small errors. As mentioned by Matte, in UTM, deviations are around 25 cm per km; Gauß-Krüger uses narrower zones, but without UTM's scale factor, so the deviations are approximately the same.