# Nearest neighbour joins for two geodataframes using KDtree from scipy/sklearn

Tags: qgis, python, geopandas, scipy

I have a number of large geodataframes and I want to automate the implementation of a *Nearest Neighbour* function using a *KDtree* for more efficient processing. The process I want to achieve here is to find the nearest neighbour to a point in one dataframe (gdA) and attach a single attribute value from this nearest neighbour in gdB.

This is effectively the function performed by the `NNjoin` package in QGIS. The code written below (with help from this link [GeoPandas: Find nearest point in other dataframe](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222315/geopandas-find-nearest-point-in-other-dataframe)) succeeds in generating the same distances as `NNjoin`, but unfortunately does not return anything like the same attribute values.

#### OPTION 1

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

def ckdnearest(gdA, gdB, bcol):   
nA = np.array(list(zip(gdA.geometry.x, gdA.geometry.y)) )
nB = np.array(list(zip(gdB.geometry.x, gdB.geometry.y)) )
btree = cKDTree(nB)
dist, idx = btree.query(nA,k=1)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'distance': dist.astype(int),
                             'bcol' : gdB.loc[idx, bcol].values })
return df

SW_closest = ckdnearest(gdA, gdB, 'attribute_value')
```

#### OPTION 2

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree

def ckdnearest(gdA, gdB, bcol):   
nA = np.array(list(zip(gdA.geometry.x, gdA.geometry.y)) )
nB = np.array(list(zip(gdB.geometry.x, gdB.geometry.y)) )
btree = KDTree(nB)
dist, idx = btree.query(nA, k=1)
idx = idx[:,0]
index = idx.flatten()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'distance': dist.astype(int),
                             'bcol' : gdB.loc[index, bcol].values})
return df

SW_closest2 = ckdnearest(gdA, gdB, 'attribute_value')}
```

Comment: have you looked at [this link](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/site/notebooks/L3/nearest-neighbor-faster.html)? Seems similar to the problem you're having **if we're talking efficiency in nearest neighbor for large dataset**. Although This uses `BallTree`, I think you can change `BallTree` to `KDTree`, I haven't tried it.

Comment: @sutan thank you so much!