# How to avoid geopy time out problem with nominatim?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, nominatim, geopy

I am using geopy with nominatim to get cities names from geographic coordinates.
I am using the below code :

```
for index,row in data.iterrows():
    georeverse = geolocator.reverse
    locationdep = georeverse(row[3],language='fr-FR',exactly_one=True)
    address = location.raw['address']
    state=address.get('state','')
    town=address.get('town','')
```

My problem is that it throws a time out error after treating 256 rows and my data frame contain over 100 000 rows.
So how would I handle this to avoid the timeout error?

Comment: Hey, welcome to GIS SE! Can you share the code youi are using to create a `geopy.geocoders.Nominatim` instance?

Comment: this is the code I used `from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim`                                                   `geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="class-app")` @MarceloVilla-Piñeros

Comment: What happens if you specify a timeout? For example,  `Nominatim(user_agent="class-app", timeout=10)`. Furthermore, you could add a `try`/`except` clause to skip the rows where a time out happens.

Comment: On another note, where are your cities located? If they are not all over the world, a better approach might be downloading a shapefile with the cities geometries and doing an intersection or a nearest neighbour analysis.

Comment: Yes my cities are located in one country which is Algeria. Can you please explain more for me from where could I download a shape file ? and how can I apply the nearest neighbor analysis approach I have been looking for something like that and I couldn't find it. Thank you for helping me @MarceloVilla-Piñeros

Comment: You can download the administrative areas (with different level of subdivisions) for different countries either [here](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata) or [here](https://data.humdata.org/dataset/algeria-administrative-boundaries-levels-1-2-populated-places). These are polygons you can use to intersect your coordinates with. If these polygons do not meet your requirements, you can download a shapefile with populated places (*i.e.* cities) in Algeria and follow one of the approaches proposed in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/222315/86131).

Comment: Nominatim is free thus it has very low rate limits. RateLimiter might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51573613 , or you can consider using another (paid) geocoding service with more quota.